# Logged session goes to all url

Tags: php, session

I have two users `me` & `bai`.

If `me` logins it goes to http://localhost/Ebooks/new/me

And if `bai` logins it goes to http://localhost/Ebooks/new/bai

I am using sessions so that no one goes their respective links without `login`.

But I am facing the problem that if `bai` is logged in, and the user types `http://localhost/Ebooks/new/me` in the URL bar, it goes to that folder, but it should not as logged in user is another.

The code goes here:-

http://localhost/Ebooks/new/**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect($logout);
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($uname,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect($uname);
    }
}
?>
```

http://localhost/Ebooks/new/**class.user.php**

```
public function login($uname,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
    }
```

http://localhost/Ebooks/new/bai/index.php & http://localhost/Ebooks/new/me.php both have :-

```
<?php require_once '../home.php' ?>
```

http://localhost/Ebooks/new/home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect($web);
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Please help me, how to clear it out!

Comment: Can you provide a archive or a zip file or an explanation of what you are trying to do. I would want to give the best possible response for your circumstances.

Comment: you have to call function in `http://localhost/Ebooks/new/me` after session start in which u can check whether user is authorised or not and redirect according to user type

Comment: @Pritamkumar I have edited the question with two more pages in last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution:

store username also in session. So in login

```
 $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
 $_SESSION['user_name'] = $userRow['userName'];
```

Then in home.php check username with path

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $_SESSION['user_name'])
    {
       //show error or redirect to user page
    }
    else
    {
    //continue your code

    }
```

**EDIT**    try edited code for url checking (in home.php)

```
$url =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$exp = explode("/",$url);
$match_name= "";
if(isset($exp[count($exp)-2]) && $exp[count($exp)-2] != "")
{
    $match_name= $exp[count($exp)-2];
}
elseif(isset($exp[count($exp)-1]) && $exp[count($exp)-1] != "")
{
     $match_name= $exp[count($exp)-1];
}
if($match_name != $_SESSION['user_name'])
        {
           //show error or redirect to user page
        }
        else
        {
        //continue your code

        }
```

Comment: where should I place  $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
 $_SESSION['user_name'] = $userRow['username'];

Comment: in `login` function. You already have `$_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];` only need one extra session `if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        return true;
                    }`

Comment: Now, I am trying to log in with user `me` then also it logouts. As per your instruction I edited `class.user.php` and `home.php`. My new `home.php` code is

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
 $user_home->redirect($web);
}
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $_SESSION['user_name'])
    {
       $user_home->redirect($web);//show error or redirect to user page
    }
    else

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>`

Comment: what is the output of `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: did not get what are you asking?

Comment: write `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; die;` at the top of your `home.php` file and tell what is the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154224/discussion-between-chiru-and-b-desai).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, compare the requested directory with the user's username and see if they match, if they do, show it, other wise show them an error message.

```
<?php
$exists = strrpos($url, '/');
$requested_username = $exists === false ? false : substr($url, $exists + 1);

if ($requested_username == $_SESSION['username_here']) {
    /** Pass... **/
} else {
    /**  Fail... **/
}
?>
```

You'd replace `$url` with the requested URL.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/Ky4f)

Comment: how to compare?

Comment: I have edited the question with two more pages in last.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the session on "me" page, if user is authorised then go on otherwise redirect him to "bai" page. And same to other type user.